# UWP horizontal list of subpages

Tags: binding, uwp

I'm currently working on my first UWP project. I managed to display subpages using `<local:ClassName/>`. But now I want to make it more dynamically.

I have a small 340*693 page and I want to display 0 up to 4 of them side by side on my mainpage. Furthermore I want to be able to switch to an edit-mod (similar to the 8.1 metro ui) where I can change the order of the subpages, or close them by moving them down.

I thought of a vector with subpages that is bound to a list or grid or something like that to store the subpages.

What container would be the right one for me?

Comment: Did you look at `BladeView` from UWP Community Toolkit?

Comment: That looks really nice, but i don't want that close and move button on the top. It should be similar to IOs Homescreen editing. I change the mod (right tap or via button) and then i can close and move the panels. I don't want to resize them

Comment: I just noticed that UWP is only for c#. My project is c++ so i cannot use it. Furthermore i'm working on an Windows 8.1 compatible App.